# Talend RunIf Trigger Condition is not working

Tags: java, talend

I am using Run if Trigger in talend with the below condition

`(String)globalMap.get("row3.STATUS")=="ACTIVE"`.

The Value getting passed is ACTIVE but the trigger is failing and giving status as false instead of TRUE.

Please advice whether I wrote the condition in the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in the Run-if are Java expressions.  So you have to do a String based equivalency test.

Used this instead

```
((String)globalMap.get("row3.STATUS")).equals("ACTIVE")
```